# How might I simulate a private browsing experience in Watir? (Selenium)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, privacy

Watir is a Selenium-based black-box testing tool that can automate tasks on the browser.

I would like to be able to open up a Watir::Browser.new that is in private browsing mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Firefox (I am not sure about the other browsers), you can setup the profile to have private browsing enabled:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.privatebrowsing.dont_prompt_on_enter'] = true
profile['browser.privatebrowsing.autostart'] = true
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

This was the solution from https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/95. 
It seems to work (at least the main menu says it is private browsing).

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome

`browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, switches: ['--incognito']`