# Selenium: Check if the current window is a private window or normal window?

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, selenium

Is there a way in Selenium web driver (python, Firefox) to check that the current window is in private mode(private window so the cookies won't be cached) or it is just a normal window?

Comment: I certainly hope not!

Comment: Have a look at [incognito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode). looks like you are starting with a new profile each time.

Comment: I'm sad to say that [this](https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956) works for me

Comment: Actually I have open a mixed of private and normal windows in Selenium, and I need to check at some point which one is which. So I'm looking for some selenium command or firefox flag to check that.

Answer (score 4):

Selenium actually already runs private mode by default. Every time you start any driver via Selenium it creates a brand new anonymous profile. This of course if you haven't specified an already created profile.

Comment: "this is 100% correct."  - a Selenium project maintainer

Comment: @sircapsalot thank you for contributing to such an awesome piece of software! ;)

Comment: it's a collaborative effort :)  hence open source!

Comment: Yes, it is a fresh profile but then cookies would be stored there while you are visiting domains. I need to open private windows and then close them to delete cookies.So I need a way to detect if the widow that I'm closing is a private window or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the path of the browser's profile, like:

```
# start a Firefox named `ff`
> ff.firefox_profile.path
'/var/folders/v3/vnzplyt50796n0tvgb2rvwm00000gn/T/tmppe0Pwx'
```

If you've pointed a existing profile, it would be named as `webdriver-py-profile-namecopy`: [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py)

Comment: But if I open a normal page and then open a private window, it still uses the same profile, so It can not help.