# How to open a private firefox window - selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I run my selenium web driver in firefox private mode instead of just normal firefox?

I tried the below but it hasn't worked:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

I viewed the question asked before which is mentioned in the comment and above the question but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Selenium incognito/private mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode)

Comment: You May Like To See This : [Python/Selenium incognito/private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023783/9989034)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FirefoxBinary` and `add_command_line_options`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

b = firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
b.add_command_line_options("-private")
dr = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=b)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work when copying the code in the file. Is there something I need to change as it couldn't find the directory?

Comment: @BruceyBandit, I use ubuntu so my binary is in `/usr/bin`, what OS are you using?

Comment: @BruceyBandit, you need to pass the path to the firefox .exe

Answer (score 1):

Providing an updated answer for 2024. Selenium now uses options to do these things. One sticking point I've not seen mentioned is that you need to use the "-private-window" flag instead of just "-private", or it will open a window that says you are not in private mode and then open normal tabs. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.binary_location = FIREFOX_LOCATION
opt.add_argument("-private-window")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt)
```