# find_element_by_name does not work in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

Yesterday everything worked fine, but today I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bot.py", line 31, in
>   
>       ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')   File "bot.py", line 13, in **init**
>       self.login()   File "bot.py", line 20, in login
>       self.driver.find_element_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".username"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=77.0.3865.90)

I've tried to find element by class name, xpath but none of these worked.

**bot.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
        self.base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com'

        self.login()


    def login(self):

        self.driver.get('{}/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher'.format(self.base_url))
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)

        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")[0].click()

    def nav_user(self, user):
        self.driver.get('{}/{}/'.format(self.base_url, user))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')

    ig_bot.nav_user('garyvee')
```

**html**

```
<input class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: it would be better if you can provide the more HTML code or screenshot. Also, you can add the code to let the wait chrome driver till the time of it's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the page and it does work, you should simply use `find_element_by_name` instead of by `find_element_by_class_name`.

output from the chrome console:

```
document.getElementsByName("username")[0];

<input class=​"_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" aria-label=​"Phone number, username, or email" aria-required=​"true" autocapitalize=​"off" autocorrect=​"off" maxlength=​"75" name=​"username" type=​"text" value autocomplete=​"off" style=​"background-image:​ url("data:​image/​png;​base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAkCAYAAADo6zjiAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAnVJREFUWAntVzuL4lAUPokBsVB0t9odK8VCLCal3Q4WbmUpCFv6DyymEmys9gf4B4RlS7GwEWQsBAsL195q2J3KWIiVrz0nJBcTk9yr3jCw7AG5j3PO9325j2OiAFq73X7Y7/​ffsft0Op0+05wsUxTlD2K9aJr23Gw2f7txFYv8FxJ/​dDtljlHICkU8ukWo9ORhk9ODEIe1yo7nUnH05JgJd3DBpcre8yD9Xly0Au9q/​7aAfD4PjUYDqPWzUFegUChAIpEAav0sVAF4901eu/​USEaoAL0L3nENANBqFbDYLqVTKHQe3+i6AXBOaPU4mk1Cv1yEej8PxeIR+vw/​z+dx03+qzsYNatgLFYtEkp2BVVaFUKrG8W30MIKDDBATEhOpiAqbTKWw2G5OMtmA0GjHiW30MIKCjtFqtk+2ng5ZOp8EwDFiv1/​a02Qb5HIGcAV7JNwwZW+8Hrw4BnFypbhRioAidbYFUdAEw/​Gf8QO8H7ybA0viF1QEB0cIhmUwGqtUqxGIxM2cymcBwOLzIx1X4JF0A1YxyuWzWkgtGjwlpAiKRCFQqFdB13YPGf0qagFqtBrlczmSiOkJGFZVnKl4Hem+/​26hYEfHhcIBerwe73U4IkyS+CEVygpbLJQwGA+h2u7BYLIC2RMSwFmjPeB+/​4om8+8NkNpsxzqCXEBaEHZW+VFDEIyb8kLUd5wS8vnkIrc+lb7xg8p/​/​d4jE82L4x5SHcKf/​v4CrCxEe1Deq4byVX61WrBBtt1vPcMK6WgAijfFX80Q8m+x0Omcj3+746jNAdQOVG76Qgg7CIKyrBeCVfcVEHQF+0hIK8rEwyqFcwiCsv+R847qxq2vXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")​;​ background-repeat:​ no-repeat;​ background-attachment:​ scroll;​ background-size:​ 16px 18px;​ background-position:​ 98% 50%;​">​
```

Comment: Edited my question. I copied my code wrong way, this line is by name not classname:
'self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)'

Comment: Does your selenium web driver run in private mode? if not you might have some cookies or something making you land in a page that says something like "Is this you? do you want to switch accounts?"
You can try to run selenium with a GUI (not headless) and try to see if you land on that page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode