# Selenium, how not to open incognito mode when I execute

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

When I execute

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/sunghunkwak/PythonTesting/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://gmail.com")
```

it always opens incognito mode (secrete, private mode).
But, I want to use the original Chrome. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Selenium incognito/private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode)

Comment: that is for private window, OP wants normal window so do I.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit your chrome driver like that

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("user-data-dri=C:\\Users\\<Your User on Windows>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
driver.get("put your url"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if you have added some arguments into the Chrome options, i.e:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

Comment: I haven't added this argument, but it always opens incognito Chrome.